# SQLAlchemy menu items hierarchy/ordering

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am pretty new to ORM so I need some help with creating menu for my Flask app. I have implemented model MenuItem (src is below).

Bullet-points are:

- It has one-to-many relationship with itself.
- It has many-to-many relationship with model `Role`

My questions:

1. Can I skip removing non-accessible child objects in generate_menu fn? This code (call of recursive method mark_restricted) looks too complicated, I wonder if it can be done in ORM query?
2. What is the best practice for implementing menu item ordering?

Thx guys!

```py
class MenuItem(db.Model):
    """
    Menu item model

    """

    __tablename__ = 'sa_menu_item'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sa_menu_item.id'))    
    text = db.Column(db.String(100))
    view = db.Column(db.String(100))
    icon = db.Column(db.String(50))
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    children = db.relationship('MenuItem')
    allowed_roles = db.relationship('Role',
                    secondary=menu_role
                    ,backref='menu_item')

    def __init__(self, text, view=None, icon=None):

        self.text = text
        self.view = view
        self.icon = icon

    def accessible_for(self, provided_set):

        for role in self.allowed_roles:
            if role.match(provided_set): return True
        return False

    def mark_restricted(self, lst, priv, not_allowed):
        """ Adds menu items restricted by priv to not_allowed list  """

        if not self.accessible_for(priv):
            if self in lst:
                not_allowed.append(lst.index(self))
            return

        if self.children is not None:
            for child in self.children:
                if not child.accessible_for(priv):
                    self.children.remove(child)
                else:
                    child.mark_restricted(lst, priv,not_allowed)

    @classmethod
    def generate_menu(cls, provided_set):
        """Generates menu based on provided_set of permissions""" 

        not_allowed = []

        lst = MenuItem.query.filter(MenuItem.parent_id == None, MenuItem.active == True, MenuItem.children != None).all()

        for item in lst:
            item.mark_restricted(lst,provided_set,not_allowed)

        lst = [i for j, i in enumerate(lst) if j not in not_allowed]

        return lst
```

Comment: One ORM query will be translated into one SQL query. If you believe this can be done, why don´t you post an SQL query that does the job, and we will figure out how to make it from SA ORM.

Comment: My approach would be to apply restriction on role attribute of joined table(s). I do not insist on doing #1 via SQLAlchemy, I was more interested in SA best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented custom menu item ordering by adding additional attribute `order = db.Column(db.Integer)` and by adding following line to generate_menu fn:

```
item.children.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('order'))
```